# network info on Mac OS X from terminal prompt

Tags: terminal, osx-mountain-lion

I need get network info on the Mac from terminal prompt, in linux I usually get this
info by profiles

[image]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a program running on OSX. Look at http://apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: take a look at `netstat`  `man netstat`

Comment: I'm developing a ruby gem, so this question is in order to show this stats in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @doon,

Here is the solution

```
netstat -ib | grep -e "en1" -m 1 | awk '{print $10}'
```